# git suddenly requires sudo to be able to push

Tags: git, github

The only thing I can think of could be related was adding the following to `~/.ssh/config`

```
host github.com
 HostName github.com
 IdentityFile /Users/miranda/.ssh/miranda_git
 User git
```

Debug

```
mirandazhang@Mac$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi miranda You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
mirandazhang@Mac$ git push
git@gist.github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

`$ sudo git push` is fine, same with clone a public gist, it also needs `sudo`.

---

### Edit

Permission on my key files:

```
-rw-------   1 mirandazhang miranda_zhang_q_git
-rw-r--r--   1 mirandazhang miranda_zhang_q_git.pub
```

Comment: Does your user actually own/have access to the identity file?

Comment: Seems fine to me, please see edit.

Comment: maybe the url to the remote is wrong? how does the remote look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not using the correct key.  Your push remote uses `gist.github.com`, but your SSH configuration refers only to `github.com`.  SSH has no way of knowing that these should use the same credentials.

You can either add an additional stanza for `gist.github.com`, or you can adjust the `Host` line to read `Host github.com gist.github.com` so that the correct key is used for both Gist and non-Gist content on GitHub.